# Where can I get amazon API for category list

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, categories

I want the category hierarchy of the amazon site. I need to extract all the category, sub category, sub sub category up to least level.

I need to develop discount finder of amazon , for that i want api of amazon , which can give me complete list of product category and sub category..

To build something like [this](http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/shopping/cheap-amazon-loopholes)

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [BrowseNodeLookup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodeLookup.html) method:

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService&
Operation=BrowseNodeLookup&
BrowseNodeId=1036682&
AssociateTag=yourTag
&Service=AWSECommerceService
&Timestamp=timestamp
&Signature=yourSignature
```

`BrowseNodeId` is ID of parent browse node. You can find some browse nodes IDs to start with [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodeIDs.html).

Answer (score 5):

you can find locale categories at the link [locale categories link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/LocaleIN.html) and use these nodes to find child nodes

Comment: Just what I need... Thank you @rakeshyadvanshi